# When I try to run my code, it cannot find the file

Tags: lua

So, I have a Code Runner, which works fine(it is used to run stuff easier) and I am trying to run a simple command using lua. I am trying to run print("Hello World") but everytime I try to run it, I get this
"[Running] lua "c:\Users(My Name)\Documents\VisualCodeLua\Test.Lua"
'lua' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.039 seconds"

Please Help

Comment: Please include actual code, without it it's simply impossible to even guess what's wrong.

Comment: I put I am trying to run print("Hello World").

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using Windows, and the command processor doesn't know what folder your `lua.exe` is in. You need to make sure that the folder that contains `lua.exe` is in your `PATH` environment variable. For instance, if your `lua.exe` is at `C:\Users\Yourname\Lua\5.3\lua.exe`, then you need to add `C:\Users\yourname\Lua\5.3` to the PATH variable. You can do a web search or just search Stack Overflow to find out how to change the PATH variable. For example, [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/set-path-environment-variables-in-windows-10/) is how to do it in Windows 10 using the Control Panel.